# Getting sum of field through polymorphic relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models, Payments_Distribution and Donation.

In my Donation model:

```php
public function payments() {
    return $this->morphToMany(Payments_Distribution::class, 'payable');
}
```

And I can save a payment distribution to the donation model using the following:

```php
$distribution = new Payments_Distribution;
$distribution->payment_id = $payment->id;
$amount = $request->payment_details['amount'][$i];

$donation->payments()->save($distribution);
```

But I'm stuck on how to retrieve the sum of all the associated records' amount fields in the Payment_Distribution model table.

Would it be something like:

```php
$donation->payments()->______ ->sum('amount');
```

Or something else? I'm still a bit new to polymorphic relationships.

Comment: Do you mean `$donation->payments()->sum('amount');`?

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, but I received this error: Call to a member function sum() on integer. The field is currently DECIMAL(15,2) and the sum function worked in the past. That's why I was wondering if something changed because of the relationship type.

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: How about without the parentheses `$donation->payments->sum('amount');`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not saving `amount` to the `Payments_Distribution` instance before using the `->save()` method. Replace:

```
$amount = $request->payment_details['amount'][$i];
```

With:

```
$donation->amount = $request->payment_details['amount'][$i];
```